is there any way to spin up Azure arc runners on nodes with certain specific architecture?
While configuring azure arc runners to run github actions, we might have some platform related images, which requires specific architecture like arm64 or amd64.
Is there any way to mention arc runners controller spinning up in k8s cluster, to specify the architecture to the runner pods to be spinning up.
In my case I have a sql which needs arm64 architecture. I have configured azure arc runners with below configuration.
values.yaml
containerMode:
  type: "dind"


arc.tf
resource "helm_release" "arc" {
  repository = "oci://ghcr.io/actions/actions-runner-controller-charts"
  chart      = "gha-runner-scale-set-controller"
  name       = "arc-controller"
  namespace  = kubernetes_namespace.arc_systems.metadata[0].name
}

resource "helm_release" "arc_runners" {
  namespace  = kubernetes_namespace.arc_systems.metadata[0].name
  repository = "oci://ghcr.io/actions/actions-runner-controller-charts"
  chart      = "gha-runner-scale-set"
  name       = "azure-arc-runners"

  set {
    name  = "githubConfigUrl"
    value = "https://github.com/praja"
  }

  set {
    name  = "githubConfigSecret"
    value = kubernetes_secret.github_secret.metadata[0].name
  }

  set {
    name  = "minRunners"
    value = "0"
  }

  set {
    name  = "maxRunners"
    value = "5"
  }

  set {
    name  = "runnerScaleSetName"
    value = "azure-arc-runners"
  }

  values = [
    templatefile("${path.module}/values.yaml", {})
  ]

}


We have multiple nodes configured with amd64 and arm64 architecture in our k8s cluster in azure.
It is causing some runner pods are being spinning up on amd64 node machine, which is causing our github workflow to fail, due to architecture mismatch of mysql image, we are fetching in the workflow.
So we need to have specific configuration, so that we can specify runner pods to be spinned up on arm64 node machine.
But when I have been go through arc runner controller charts and values, there is no parameter to mention about runner pods architecture specification.
is there any way to resolve this?
github issue

I was able to solve this problem by adding below configuration to the vaules.yaml
template:
  spec:
    nodeSelector:
      "kubernetes.io/arch": arm64

now was able to spin up runner pods on arm64 node machine.
